# How to retain data securely on browser refresh in angularja?

Tags: angularjs

I have authorization data received after calling service. On browser refresh I want retain the data securely and avoid a service call. Please suggest.

Comment: localStorage is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon your requirements if you want to do with angularjs cookie you can go with it or if you can also use local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

localStorage.setItem('data', data);

or

$window.localStorage.data = JSON.stringify(data);

It won't get deleted on page refresh. You can see data in local storage.

You can use cookies as well, those are used for authorization mostly, it is secure than local storage as well as they can be expired in some time.